# WebDriver unable to locate element /p

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate element p, which is a blank text area to fill, however webdriver throws exception that element is not found. I have tried:

```
css = "#tinymce>p"
xpath = "//*[@id='tinymce']/p"
```

on the following page

`<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody aui-theme-default wiki-content fullsize page-edit" contenteditable="true"onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('wysiwygTextarea').onLoad.dispatch();" dir="ltr" style="padding-top: 100px;">
  <p>
    <br/>
  </p>`

Answer (score 0):

You have xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", which means you will have to ask p with the namespace included.

```
xpath = "//*[@id='tinymce']/*[local-name() = 'p']"
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

i use nth-child function with cssselector.

```
#tinymce p:nth-child(1)
```

Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5sz0Ly8/)